# saving pil image objects in to a folder

Tags: python, image, save, python-imaging-library

I am trying to save PIL image objects ()  to a folder but don't know how. I couldn't find any tips online.
I would appreciate any help.
Here is my code

input_path = "some location"

image_files = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(input_path, "**/*.*), recursive=True))

output_path =

os.path.join(os.path.dirname(input_path),os.path.basename(input_path) +"_12345")

os.makedirs(output_path, exist_ok=True)

for file in image_files:

```
file = Image.open(file) # This returns a PIL image
image = np.array(file)
variance = np.var(image)
if variance > 0:   
    im = Image.fromarray(image)
```

Here i tried to use shutil.copy() it didn't work. Image.save(fp, format) also didn't work. 
The traceback errors were somehow trivial but i still couldn't find a solution for it. 
Again the goal is to save all these image objects to a folder if they have 
variance greater Zero. Thanks

Comment: Can you give a bit more clarification on what happens when you try `Image.save('Filename.extension')`? I tried the code you did, and `im.save('Name.png')` worked to save an image for me.

Comment: yes i can save also save one pic but not all the pics.
im_obj.save(output_dir, "JPEG") 
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: home/output_dir2

Comment: So when you iterate through the images it saves one image but not the rest of them, and you're trying to save them all under different names?

Comment: when i try to use shutil.copy it throws an attributeError: expected strings or bytes but got an Image object
Before when i did copy the images to folder with ease but after converting it to numpy array to calculate the variance it somehow was not possible to copy these image objects as pics to a folder.

Comment: yes correct. your right